# Web Api Owin Hosted - Throughput dropping

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

We've recently copied an api that we have from being IIS hosted into a console app (to be hosted with Owin + TopShelf as a service) and have been performance profiling the two hosting options using JMeter.

We throw 18 threads at the apis and we get differing results back from the IIS hosted vs console hosted, specifically as follows :

Response times through IIS are slower. This isn't surprising as the pipeline in IIS is more involved.

Throughput through IIS is consistent, i.e. we don't see significant increases/decreases in throughput (we achieve 5500 requests/responses per min)

Throughput when hosted in a console app starts off very high (20,000 per min) but degrades quickly to approximately 4,500 per min over a 10 minute period.

We're trying to determine what the cause of this throughput drop is when hosting as a console. Why is we start with 20,000 requests per min (presumably calculated on initial response times when it hasn't run for a minute) but degrade to 4,500?

Other things of note, CPU isn't a concern. It's fluctuates to start but settles below 30% available, and memory is average 1.34GB on a 4GB ram machine.

Why might the throughput in IIS be stable and why does it degrade when hosted in using MS Owin hosting through a console app (given stable CPU and Memory)?

Incidentally we're trying to isolate pieces of code that could cause the degradation.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally I don't know whether this is an issue in our code, our expectations, the way JMeter establishes/predicts throughput. If there are any other recommended tools for varying input and testing througput/response times then please recommend.

Comment: Could you solve this problem?